# how to give the fade in and fade out effect in embed tag and object Tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to give the fade in and fade out effect in embed tag and  object Tag?

```
'<object width="140" height="185"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/blsg_rRAg0I?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/blsg_rRAg0I?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="140" height="185"></object>').appendTo('#VideoWrp')
```

whn i open this VideoWrp container , its not c

Comment: I think you accidentally something.

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be done with a .live() action because your content appears to be dynamically created (your use of .appendTo()).  If fadeIn() and fadeOut() don't work directly on embed and object tags, here's a trick: You could cover the embed and object tags with a solid coloured DIV (doesn't work in Chrome), using a transparent wmode attribute; then, simply apply the fadeIn and fadeOut to the DIV tag (except use fadeOut to fadeIn the object and embed tags).  Do you get what I'm saying?  Hope this works. :)

Answer (score 0):

i was having a similar problem with jquery fadeIn() fadeOut() methods
i chose to go with an instant change to hidden

```
$("#object_id").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

and an instant change back to visible

```
$("#object_id").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

hope this helps